# What is name of this software can draw tables relationship?

Tags: entity-relationship

I like to draw tables relationship as below, but I don't know what software, does anyone help me?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagram looks like those created by MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Which menu in MySQL workbench? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Try File | New Model | Add Diagram or Create New EER Model in the Data Modeling section of Workbench Central.

Comment: I noticed I'm still using 5.2, so my info may be outdated.

Comment: Thanks, I found it! By the way, how can I draw Model for exist Schema or tables?

Comment: It has an option to Create EER Model from Existing Database, or click Database | Reverse Engineer.  Alternatively, just draw it to match an existing schema, if it's not too big.

Answer (score 1):

Try Valentina Studio. It has a free version, which includes table viewer like on your picture.
http://www.valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-key-features

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am downloading it to try. By the way, no any plugins can be used in eclipse?